# Import-CSV to Get-ADUser

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to make a very simple script work that reads a CSV with 100 SamAccountName/Identities into a variable and then returns AD Users with all Objects from Get-ADUser.

The CSV only contains usernames (1 each line) so essentially it could also be a simple text file.

I feel like I'm very close but I can't make it work for some reason.

```
$users= (Import-CSV 'C:\Temp\users.csv') # <-- Doesn't work

#$users= "backupservice","name01" <-- This Works

ForEach ($user in $users) 

{
Get-ADUser $user -Properties *
}
```

Here's the error message when I am trying to read the CSV into the loop:

```
Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The Identity property on the argument is null or empty.
At line:8 char:16
+     Get-ADUser $user -Properties *
+                ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

Okay, so I have an issue with parameter binding but I am not sure how to fix it.

I would appreciate any input/insight you could give me.

Thank you!

Comment: Does the CSV file have a header row?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: Then it's not a CSV, it's just a list of usernames. Use `Get-Content` instead of `Import-Csv` and it'll work.

Comment: That was pretty dumb, wasn't it! Thanks. ‍♂️✔

Comment: I haven't had coffee yet, it sounds pretty relatable ^_^ Your welcome

Answer (score 1):

I actually just now took the original CSV (which had two columns [SamAccountName and UPN]) and fixed it just now with the following code:

```
    $users = (Import-CSV "C:\Temp\Test001.csv" | Select SamAccountName -ExpandProperty SamAccountName)

    ForEach ($user in $users) 

    {

    Get-ADUser $user -Properties * #| Export-CSV 'C:\Temp\users_expanded.csv'-Append
    
    }
```

Is there a better way to do this? The journey continues.

Comment: How about `Import-CSV "C:\Temp\Test001.csv" | ForEach-Object { Get-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName -Properties * } | Export-CSV 'C:\Temp\users_expanded.csv'-NoTypeInformation`